# Create a recycler view insider a recycler view in android

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

If I want to create a recycler view insider a recycler view in android, how to handle the view holder in the first container of recycler view and how to handle the transmission in two recycler view? Please give me some suggestion. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Problem Statement** : We have to display three items in parent recycler view. First two items are normal cardViews and the third item is child recycler view.

[image: Screenshot]

```
 The top two items are card views and the third item is a list of hotels.
```

---

**MainActivity.class** :

```
public class **MainActivity** extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    ArrayList<DataModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new DataModel("Bus"));
    items.add(new DataModel("Flight"));
    ArrayList<String> hotelsList=new ArrayList<>();
    hotelsList.add("Hotel 1");
    hotelsList.add("Hotel 2");
    hotelsList.add("Hotel 2");
    items.add(new DataModel("Hotels",hotelsList));
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    ParentAdapter parentAdapter = new ParentAdapter(items,MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(parentAdapter);
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DataModel.class**

```
public class DataModel {

  private String title;
  private ArrayList<String> hotels;

  public DataModel(String title){
    this.title=title;
  }

  public DataModel(String title, ArrayList<String> hotels){
    this.title=title;
    this.hotels=hotels;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getHotels() {
    return hotels;
  }

}
```

**ParentAdapter.class** : Parent Recycler View

```
   public class ParentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

      private ArrayList<DataModel> items;
      private Context mContext;

      public ParentAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> items, Context mContext) {
        this.items = items;
        this.mContext=mContext;
      }


      @Override
      public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if (viewType == ViewType.NORMAL_ITEM) {
          return new NormalHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.normal_view, parent, false));
        } else if (viewType == ViewType.HOTELS_LIST_ITEM) {
          return new ListHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false));
        }
        return null;
      }


      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int cardType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (cardType) {
          case ViewType.NORMAL_ITEM:
            NormalHolder normalHolder=(NormalHolder) holder;
            normalHolder.title.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
            break;
          case ViewType.HOTELS_LIST_ITEM:
            ListHolder listHolder=(ListHolder) holder;
            HotelCardAdapter hotelCardAdapter = new HotelCardAdapter(mContext, items.get(position).getHotels());
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            listHolder.hotelsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            listHolder.hotelsList.setAdapter(hotelCardAdapter);
            break;
        }
      }

      private interface ViewType {
        int NORMAL_ITEM = 0;
        int HOTELS_LIST_ITEM = 1;
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
          return ViewType.NORMAL_ITEM;
        } else return ViewType.HOTELS_LIST_ITEM;
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
      }

      private class NormalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        public NormalHolder(View inflate) {
          super(inflate);
          title=inflate.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
      }

      private class ListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView hotelsList;

        public ListHolder(View inflate) {
          super(inflate);
          hotelsList = inflate.findViewById(R.id.hotel_list);
        }
      }
    }
```

**normal_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                                        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="6dp">


        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Bus"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/view_all"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="View All"
          android:textSize="12sp"/>


      </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**list_view.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                                        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp">

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/header"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hotels"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/hotel_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/header"
          android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal"/>


      </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**HotelCardAdapter.class** : Child Recycler View

```
public class HotelCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private ArrayList<String> hotelsObject;
  private Context context;

  public HotelCardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> hotelsObject) {
    this.hotelsObject = hotelsObject;
    this.context = context;

  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new HotelCarouselHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_carousel_item, null));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HotelCarouselHolder hotelCarouselHolder = (HotelCarouselHolder) holder;
    hotelCarouselHolder.title.setText(hotelsObject.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return hotelsObject.size();
  }

  private class HotelCarouselHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title;

    public HotelCarouselHolder(View inflate) {
      super(inflate);
      title = inflate.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
  }
}
```

**hotel_carousel_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="16dp">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hotel_details_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/hotel_image"
      android:layout_width="256dp"
      android:layout_height="144dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="#999999"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/hotel_image"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:text="Hotels 1"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!